# Artifactory 7.21.12 URL redirecting from 8081 to 8082

Tags: redirect, port, artifactory

I am trying to access my Artifactory URL with version 7.21.12, and it is always redirecting the port from 8081 to 8082, and it is showing 302.

Tried updating the port number in system.yaml file as well, but still we facing the same issue.

From this URL `http://localhost:8081/artifactory/maven-releases/` it is redirecting to `http://localhost:8082/ui/native/maven-releases/`

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behaviour in Artifactory 7.x, 8081 port is for Artifactory and 8082 for the UI access. This is because of the new Artifactory 7.x structure. I would recommend referring to the below JFrog wiki's to get a clear understanding,

1. [System requirements](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/System+Requirements)
2. [System Architecture](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/System+Architecture)